# How to overcome \n in list

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, list, text

I wanted to make a list with python from the data in a text file. I used regular expression re.split as shown in the code. But problem is at the last data in list I get \n. I do not want \n. How to solve this problem?

> My Text File which is saved as pass1.txt:

```
aizakboy miaw
```

> My Python Code is

```
with open('pass1.txt', mode = 'r') as my_file:
        passinputs = my_file.read()
        passinputs_list = re.split(' ', passinputs)
print(passinputs_list)
```

> Output:

```
['aizakboy', 'miaw\n']
```

Here last data `miaw` comes with `'miaw\n'` . I want `miaw` not `miaw\n`. What is the solution?

Comment: `passinputs = my_file.read().splitlines()`

Comment: Do you need to split up all the words of the file? Or just all the lines?

Comment: I need to split up all the words of the file. @Karl Knechtel

Comment: Check out str.splitlines(). More generally, see str.rstrip()

Comment: If I add str.rstrip() or str.splitlines() I get ['aizakboy', 'miaw', '']. Here '' is the new problem. I just want   ['aizakboy', 'miaw']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to split up all the words of the file.

Then regex is not the tool you want. It is much simpler than you expect: the *built-in* `split` method of strings has a special case to split on "any whitespace".

```
with open('pass1.txt', mode = 'r') as my_file:
    passinputs_list = my_file.read().split()
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be able to use .strip() to remove trailing characters. I used that in Learn Python the Hard Way. Exercise 23 uses it to strip trailing but hidden \n that are in a list of languages that you are to encode in UTF-8.
Their example was next_lang = line.strip()

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a regular explression to get your result.  The `split` method produces a list by default:

```
with open('pass1.txt', mode = 'r') as my_file:
        passinputs = my_file.read()
        passinputs_list = split(passinputs)
print(passinputs_list)
```

Output:

```
['aizakboy', 'miaw']
```